# Disable Responsive Behavior from telerik

Tags: telerik

Is there any way to disable Responsive Behavior from Telerik components? for example disabling it for Navigation menu?

Answer (score 0):

The adaptivity of the RadNavigation control is one of its main features and cannot be disabled. I would suggest that you use the standard RadMenu control instead, which behaves in the desired by you.